# How to avoid java.security.AccessControlException through jtwitter (twitter API) from java applet

Tags: java, security, applet, twitter

I am writing a simple applet (my first) to retrieve the most recent status from a twitter account.  This works fine when running from javaw.exe launched from within eclipse.  However, when run from a browser I get the error:

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission twitter.com:80 connect, resolve)

Any advice on how to avoid this?

The call:

```
private void updateStatus() {
    try {
        Twitter client = new Twitter("user", "pw");
        Status status = client.getStatus();
        addItem(status.toString());
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        addItem(t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The connection to the client is succeeding.  It is the getStatus() call which throws the exception.  I notice that eclipse adds "-Djava.security.policy=java.policy.applet" to javaw.exe, not sure if this has anything to do with why it works from eclipse and not from within a browser.  Frustratingly, I tried to run the same javaw.exe command directly with the same CL parameters and PATH as eclipse uses successfully.  However, when I run it directly javaw.exe exits immediately.  [jtwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php) is a simple wrapper on the Twitter API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser applets are running in a sandbox with lower security permissions. Certain operations are not allowed, such as certain GUI operations (to prevent e.g. an applet from secretly running a key logger in the background). Apparently the operation you're trying to do isn't allowed either.

To solve this, you have to sign your applet. A signed applet is allowed to run under normal security permissions. To do that you have to create a security certificate and sign your applet with [jarsigner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html).

No need to buy expensive certificates, at least not if this is a small personal project. A self-signed certificate will do (the only trouble is that the browser will pop-up a message saying "certificate could not be confirmed" or something like that).

See also: [Signed applet tutorial](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html)

Answer (score 0):

@ Dave

In addition to getting your jar signed you have to ensure the code you need marked as privileged is wrapped in a privileged block.

```
final String googleUrl = "www.google.com"
URL url = (URL) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() 
    {
        public Object run() 
        {
            try
            {
                return new URL(googleUrl);
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }  
    });
```